# problem in install pyearth in jupyter (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, jupyter-notebook, package

I try to install pyearth package by pip in jupyter notebook
but it's not work
( my python = 3.7.0 )

I need to install this package important

I found this code to install

```
git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth.git
cd py-earth
sudo python setup.py install
```

but I don't where I put it to install the package :( !

I try to copy the first line and put it in jupyter notebook but this error appear :

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Can any one help me step by step how can I install the package?

Comment: can any one help me :( ??

Comment: Is it the one being referenced [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth#installation)? If that's the one, then run in a cell in you notebook, `%conda install -c conda-forge sklearn-contrib-py-earth`. That's based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sklearn-contrib-py-earth), which looks similar to what your code references. If you aren't using Anaconda/`conda` yet , see https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution for getting the Anaconda distribution for your machine. Or see if there is a way to add git to your windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add the following paths to PATH:

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\`

`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\`

And check that these paths are correct – you may have Git installed on a different drive, or under Program Files (x86). Correct the paths if necessary.

setting PATH on Windows 10:

1. Search for "environment variable" in taskbar search
   Select "Edit the system environment variables".
2. Klik "Environment Variables" button at the bottom.
3. Double-click the "Path" entry under "System variables".
4. With the "New" button in the PATH editor,
   add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\` and `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\` to the end of the list.
5. Close, reload and re-open your console

I hope this will help you :)